# Installing lxml with static dependencies

Tags: python, installation, pip, lxml

I'm trying to install `lxml` with static dependencies on OSX using the following command:

```
STATIC_DEPS=true pip install -U lxml --no-cache-dir
```

Running this throws a nice long error:

```
Collecting lxml
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/b5/d3e0d22649c63e92cb0902847da9ae155c1e801178ab5d272308f35f726e/lxml-4.3.4.tar.gz (2.5MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.5MB 2.2MB/s
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Checking for gcc...
    Compiler error reporting is too harsh for ./configure (perhaps remove -Werror).
    ** ./configure aborting.
    Building lxml version 4.3.4.
    Latest version of zlib is 1.2.11
    Downloading zlib into libs/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz from https://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
    Unpacking zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz into build/tmp
    Latest version of libiconv is 1.16
    Downloading libiconv into libs/libiconv-1.16.tar.gz from https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.16.tar.gz
    Unpacking libiconv-1.16.tar.gz into build/tmp
    Latest version of libxml2 is 2.9.9
    Downloading libxml2 into libs/libxml2-2.9.9.tar.gz from http://xmlsoft.org/sources/libxml2-2.9.9.tar.gz
    Unpacking libxml2-2.9.9.tar.gz into build/tmp
    Latest version of libxslt is 1.1.33
    Downloading libxslt into libs/libxslt-1.1.33.tar.gz from http://xmlsoft.org/sources/libxslt-1.1.33.tar.gz
    Unpacking libxslt-1.1.33.tar.gz into build/tmp
    Starting build in build/tmp/zlib-1.2.11
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/cy/ywx04ttn12n_xmgjf5s6sbzr0000gn/T/pip-install-27hg_iw0/lxml/setup.py", line 239, in <module>
        **setup_extra_options()
      File "/private/var/folders/cy/ywx04ttn12n_xmgjf5s6sbzr0000gn/T/pip-install-27hg_iw0/lxml/setup.py", line 150, in setup_extra_options
        STATIC_CFLAGS, STATIC_BINARIES)
      File "/private/var/folders/cy/ywx04ttn12n_xmgjf5s6sbzr0000gn/T/pip-install-27hg_iw0/lxml/setupinfo.py", line 81, in ext_modules
        multicore=OPTION_MULTICORE)
      File "/private/var/folders/cy/ywx04ttn12n_xmgjf5s6sbzr0000gn/T/pip-install-27hg_iw0/lxml/buildlibxml.py", line 412, in build_libxml2xslt
        cmmi(zlib_configure_cmd, zlib_dir, multicore, **call_setup)
      File "/private/var/folders/cy/ywx04ttn12n_xmgjf5s6sbzr0000gn/T/pip-install-27hg_iw0/lxml/buildlibxml.py", line 330, in cmmi
        call_subprocess(configure_cmd, cwd=build_dir, **call_setup)
      File "/private/var/folders/cy/ywx04ttn12n_xmgjf5s6sbzr0000gn/T/pip-install-27hg_iw0/lxml/buildlibxml.py", line 320, in call_subprocess
        raise Exception('Command "%s" returned code %s' % (cmd_desc, returncode))
    Exception: Command "./configure --prefix=/private/var/folders/cy/ywx04ttn12n_xmgjf5s6sbzr0000gn/T/pip-install-27hg_iw0/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2" returned code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/cy/ywx04ttn12n_xmgjf5s6sbzr0000gn/T/pip-install-27hg_iw0/lxml/
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this snag? Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: In case anyone else lands here just wanting to install `lxml`, I did so with `easy_install lxml`, which sidesteps the error above...

Comment: Can you rerun the command with `-vvv` (e.g. `STATIC_DEPS=true pip install -U lxml -vvv`)? This should give you more output.